# Mips Procedure: Infinite for loop and Exception occurred at PC

Tags: exception, for-loop, mips, procedure

Seeing the topics on the site, however I was not able to solve my problem. I noticed that the code inside the procedure falls into an infinite for and in QTSpim I saw that the registers involved are `$s0`, `$s1`, `$t2`, and `$t4`.

After a few cycles then the message `Exception occurred at PC` then `expection 7 Bad data address`.
Here is the code, I can not figure out where mistake, I tried to write it without procedure and it works perfectly.

```
.data
string: .asciiz "Hello Simon"
string2: .asciiz ""
    .text
    .globl main

Delete_space:
addi $sp, $sp, -16
sw $s0, 0($sp)
sw $s1, 4($sp)

add $t8, $a0, $zero
lenght_string:
lb $t0, 0($t8)
beqz $t0, for #t8 contain the lenght of string
add $t8, 1
j lenght_string
for:
add $s0, $zero, $zero #i=0
add $s1, $zero, $zero #j=0

condition:
slt $t1, $s0, $t8 #i< lenght_string
beq $t1, $zero, endfor


consequence:
add $t2, $t8, $s0
lb $t3, 0($t2)
bne $t3, ' ', op1
beq $t3, ' ', else
addi $s0, $s0, 1
addi $s1, $s1, 1
j condition
op1:
add $t4, $a1, $s1
sb $t3, 0($t4)
addi $s0, $s0, 1
addi $s1, $s1, 1
j condition
else:
sub $s1, $s1, 1
addi $s0, $s0, 1
addi $s1, $s1, 1
j condition
endfor:

#end 
lw $s1, 4($sp)
lw $s0, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 16
jr $ra

main:
la $a0, string
la $a1, string2
jal Delete_space

la $a0, string2
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to copy characters from one string to the other, skipping spaces. (Maybe that's not what you're trying to do - unfortunately, I don't have time to trace the code in detail.) I think the problem is that you're copying from your source string into a data area that doesn't belong to you.

Strings aren't handled the same in Assembly as they are in a high-level language. They're nothing but a sequence of bytes - there is no concept of a String that automatically expands to contain what you put in it. And there's no concept of bounds checking.

Look at these string declarations:

```
.data
string: .asciiz "Hello Simon"
string2: .asciiz ""
```

What you've done is assigned `string` to a memory address containing the byte value `'H'`. The subsequent memory locations contain `'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'S', 'i', 'm', 'o', 'n', '\0'`.

Then, you've assigned `string2` to a memory address containing the byte value `'\0'` (a null terminator).

If you write a byte to the memory address pointed to by `string2`, it would replace the null terminator. (You would already be in trouble at this point, because the `syscall` wouldn't know where your string ends.) If you then write another byte to the memory address pointed to by `string2 + 1`, you are now writing to memory that you didn't allocate to `string2`. It might belong to some other variable that's being stored - in which case, you just overwrite what was there before. That's a "buffer overflow", and it's how poorly-written programs such as Internet Explorer get exploited by hackers.

If I'm interpreting the purpose of your program correctly, you need to create a buffer for your output that's big enough to hold it. Something like this would work, assuming your output will never be longer than your input:

```
.data
string: .asciiz "Hello Simon"
string2: .asciiz "xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: What you think is right, the program from a string source copy itself into another string with no spaces.
I tried to make the change you told me, but unfortunately the error remains the same: Exception occurred at PC, then Bad address in data / stack read.
I'm launching this program with QTSpim, but I do not think depends on the simulator.